# scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347) scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)

Tags: scala

i get the following errors when i run my application withe the few scala files names.
Any help?Thanks in advance.

```
 scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347) scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345) 
    scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) 
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) 
    scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40) 
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You appear to be calling `get` on an empty `Option`. How about posting the code instead of the stack trace?

Comment: That is not an error, but a part of a stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

`Option` object is either `None` or `Some(value)`. Calling `get`, you're trying to extract the value but you raise an error if it's `None`. Good practice with `Option` is to use `getOrElse(someDefaultValue)` or pattern matching :

```scala
val res = myOption.getOrElse("No value")

myOption match {
  case None => println("It's None")
  case Some(value) => println("It's something")
}
```

Some interesting readings : 
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-scala-option-some-none-idiom-function-java-null

Comment: You can also use a map to do something with the value of Option

Comment: Map returns a new Option. I think OP was trying to get the value inside. But correct, you can operate directly on Option.